# Instructions on compiling a java project from Google code

Tags: java, build, google-code, antisamy

I use a tool called AntiSamy ( http://code.google.com/p/owaspantisamy/ ) to sanitize user input in a project. I don't know Java. I just create the object, call its method, and it works.

Recently the project was updated on Google code, but the download package itself was not. I'm looking for clear instructions on how I can download the updated code to create my own JAR file and replace the existing one in my project, thus make use of the update.

Looking at the code branch in Google code, there are many folders and other items, so I'm not sure which parts I need, and what type of directory structure I should have.

Any have any idea what should go in the JAR file/how to do this? I'm not an experienced coder, so nothing super technical please.

Comment: downloading http://owaspantisamy.googlecode.com/files/antisamy-1.4.4.jar works for me

Comment: @Jeha, 1.4.4 does not include the last changes made three days ago.

Comment: no problem, see my answer how to build from sources

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build this project first checkout the sources:

```
svn checkout http://owaspantisamy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ owaspantisamy-read-only
```

Then change directory:

```
cd owaspantisamy-read-only/Java
```

Build the project by calling (I hope you already have maven, or get it from [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.html)):

```
mvn clean install
```

The jar you finally want is located at:

```
./antisamy/target/antisamy-1.4.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: I did not have maven. I installed and I'm running it now. The cmd prompt is saying it's downloading stuff. I'll let you know how it goes. BIG thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Maven is really downloading *a lot* at the first time.

Comment: Done. It all works, and I have the updates I wanted. Thank you once more.